# Grouping and sorting JSON records in Bash

Tags: json, sorting, group-by, jq

I'm using curl to get JSON file. My problem is that I would like to get group of 4 words in one line, then break the line, and sort it by first column.

I'm trying:

```
curl -L 'http://mylink/ | jq '.[]| .location, .host_name, .serial_number, .model'
```

I'm getting

```
"Office-1"    
"work-1"    
"11xxx111"    
"hp"    
"Office-2"    
"work-2"    
"33xxx333"    
"lenovo"    
"Office-1"    
"work-3"    
"22xxx222"    
"dell"
```

I would like to have:

```
"Office-1", "work-1", "11xxx111", "hp"    
"Office-1" "work-3", "22xxx222", "dell"    
"Office-2", "work-2", "33xxx333", "lenovo"
```

I tried  `jq -S ".[]| .location| group_by(.location)`, and few other combinations like `sort_by(.location)` but it doesn't work. I'm getting error: `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot iterate over string ("Office-1")`

Sample of my JSON file:

```json
[
  {
    "location": "Office-1",
    "host_name": "work-1",
    "serial_number": "11xxx111",
    "model": "hp"
  },
  {
    "location": "Office-2",
    "host_name": "work-2",
    "serial_number": "33xxx333",
    "model": "lenovo"
  },
  {
    "location": "Office-1",
    "host_name": "work-3",
    "serial_number": "22xxx222",
    "model": "dell"
  }
]
```

Comment: Isn't just in `jq` but piping to something like `| awk '{line==""?line=$0:line=line","$0}NR%4==0{print line; line="";}' | sort -t',' ` to print out a line every four lines and then sorting that output would be an option.

Comment: Yeah it works great. I was thinking that I can use jq for it but this will do. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort by `.location` only, without an external sort:

```
map( [ .location, .host_name, .serial_number, .model] )
| sort_by(.[0])[]
| map("\"\(.)\"") | join(", ")
```

The `", "` is per the stated requirements.

If you want the output as CSV, simply replace the last line in the jq program above by `@csv`.

If minimizing keystrokes is a goal, then if you are certain that the keys are always in the desired order, you could get away with replacing the first line by `map( [ .[] ] )`

Answer (score 2):

You can ask `jq` to produce arbitrary formatted strings.

```sh
curl -L 'http://mylink/ |
jq -r '.[]| "\"\(.location)\", \"\(.host_name)\", \"\(.serial_number)\", \"\(.model)\""' |
sort
```

Inside the double quotes, `\"` produces literal double quotes, and `\(.field)` interpolates a field name. The `-r` option is required to produce output which isn't JSON.

Comment: The Q asks for the result to be sorted by .location only, but to address the sorting requirement, it might be acceptable to write: `jq -r '[...] | sort[]` where ... is the program shown in this (partial) answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the output you wanted:

```
jq -r 'group_by(.location) | .[] | .[] | map(values) | "\"" + join ("\", \"") + "\""'
```

like so:

```
$ jq -r 'group_by(.location) | .[] | .[] | map(values) | "\"" + join ("\", \"") + "\""' /tmp/so7713.json
"Office-1", "work-1", "11xxx111", "hp"
"Office-1", "work-3", "22xxx222", "dell"
"Office-2", "work-2", "33xxx333", "lenovo"
```

If you want it all as one string, it's a bit simpler:

```
$ jq 'group_by(.location) | .[] | .[] | map(values) | join (", ")' /tmp/so7713.json
"Office-1, work-1, 11xxx111, hp"
"Office-1, work-3, 22xxx222, dell"
"Office-2, work-2, 33xxx333, lenovo"
```

Note the lack of `-r` in the second example.

I feel there has to be a better way of doing `.[] | .[]`, but I don't know what it is (yet).

Comment: `.[]|.[]` can be abbreviated to `.[][]` but it's probably cognitively easier to use @tripleee's approach, suitably augmented with a call to `sort`.